# How do I reshape Python dictionary with various list structures

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following sample object from a dictionary, and I am attempting to flatten the data so that each key-value will become its own "column" in a pandas DataFrame. As you can see, this requires handling multiple scenarios. I would want each id key within there to become it's own Column in the dataframe and then assign the respective value of the 'value' key to that Column.

I attempted to utilize the .json_normalize() which gets me close (I build the dataframe as desired if I exclude supplementalFieldValues), but I am having issues with simultaneously converting the key-values within the 'supplementalFieldValues' list into their own fields. Or would it also be an option to use the original list, without the supplementalFieldValues, then reshape the supplementalFieldValues, then join that back to the original list.

```
    {
        "classification": [
            {
                "classificationId": "OperatingExpense",
                "taxonomyId": "accounting.gp"
            }
        ],
        "supplementalFieldValues": [
            {
                "id": "Account Class",
                "value": "Expense"
            },
            {
                "id": "Account Type",
                "value": "Expense"
            },
            {
                "id": "Account Subtype",
                "value": "PayrollExpenses"
            }
        ],
        "id": "182",
        "name": "Payroll - Admin",
        "userAssignedCode": "60100"
    },
```

My desired output would look like this:
[image: sample_output]

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution cames following these steps:

1. Flatten the dictionary to create a single-level dictionary.
2. Create a DataFrame from the flattened dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your sample data
data = {
    "classification": [
        {
            "classificationId": "OperatingExpense",
            "taxonomyId": "accounting.gp"
        }
    ],
    "supplementalFieldValues": [
        {
            "id": "Account Class",
            "value": "Expense"
        },
        {
            "id": "Account Type",
            "value": "Expense"
        },
        {
            "id": "Account Subtype",
            "value": "PayrollExpenses"
        }
    ],
    "id": "182",
    "name": "Payroll - Admin",
    "userAssignedCode": "60100"
}

# Function to flatten the dictionary
def flatten_dict(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        new_key = f"{parent_key}{sep}{key}" if parent_key else key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            items.update(flatten_dict(value, new_key, sep))
        else:
            items[new_key] = value
    return items

flattened_data = flatten_dict(data)

# Create a DataFrame from the flattened dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame([flattened_data])

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Anyway, you should attach the code you are using to see what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to follow an original idea within my question. In a pandas object, I popped the items from 'supplementalFieldValues' and stored them into their own list (supp_list). This made it easier for me to utilize the defaultdict package to loop through this list while utilizing the in-place OR operator to update the value to become the key.

```
res = defaultdict(dict)
for d in supp_list:
    res[d['i']] |= {'i': d['i'], d['id']: d.get('value')}

supplemental_list = [*res.values()]
```

Now that I had my new supplemental_list, I just joined it into my original pandas object (flat_list) that had the supplementalFieldValues popped from it.

```
flat_data = flat_list.join(pd.DataFrame(supplemental_list).set_index('i')).reset_index(drop=True)
```